# UITableview first cell getting scrolled up behind navigation bar in iOS 10

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, ios10, ios11

I'm presenting a popup(myCustomViewController.m) when my viewcontroller loads. The popup is a viewcontroller which has a tableview. Below is my code on how I show the popup.

```
- (void)showTableviewpopup{

   myCustomViewController *myVC = [myCustomViewController controller];
    myVC.delegate = self;
    UINavigationController *navCtrl = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController: myVC];
    navCtrl.modalPresentationStyle = UIModalPresentationFormSheet;

    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
        [self presentViewController:navCtrl animated:YES completion:NULL];
    });
}
//This is how myCustomViewController interface looks like
    @interface myCustomViewController : UIViewController <UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate>
```

Now when this popup loads the first cell is tableview gets scrolled up behind the navigation bar and there is no way to pull it down. This works fine on iOS 11 but has issues on iOS 10. If I add the below code this fixes the issue in iOS 10 but adds additional space in iOS 11.

```
- (void)viewDidLayoutSubviews {
    UIEdgeInsets insets = UIEdgeInsetsMake(self.topLayoutGuide.length, 0, 0, 0);
    self.tableView.contentInset = insets;
    self.tableView.scrollIndicatorInsets = insets;
}
```

Another solution is to put a check for iOS 11 before I apply this code but is there a better way to solve this?

Answer (score 1):

> Another solution is to put a check for iOS 11 before I apply this code but is there a better way to solve this?

No, there isn't. 
As you rightly observe, this all works completely different in iOS 10 and iOS 11. Thus you will have to write conditional code depending on the version at runtime.

- For iOS 10, you set the `contentInset` as you have shown.
- For iOS 11, you set the `contentInsetAdjustmentBehavior` to `.always`.